# How to evaluate $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\int\int}_{(0,\infty)\times (0,\infty)} \frac{\sin^2(nxy)xy}{e^{(x^2+y^2)}}\,dx\,dy.$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

How to evaluate: $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\int\int}_{(0,\infty)\times (0,\infty)} \frac{\sin^2(nxy)xy}{e^{(x^2+y^2)}}\,dx\,dy.$$
(Hint: the purpose of this question is about application of convergence theorem. i.e. Dominated Convergence, etc.)

attempt:
$${\int\int}_{(0,\infty)\times (0,\infty)} \frac{\sin^2(nxy)xy}{e^{(x^2+y^2)}}\,dx\,dy=\int\int(-\frac{1}{2}y)sin^2(nxy)de^{-(x^2+y^2)}dxdy=$$

$$\int(-\frac{1}{2}y)\{[sin^2(nxy)2^{-(x^2+y^2)}]_{0}^\infty-\int2e^{-{(x^2+y^2)}}2sin(nxy)(ny)dx\}dy=$$

$$\int(-\frac{1}{2}y)\int2e^{-{(x^2+y^2)}}2sin(nxy)(ny)dxdy=\int(-\frac{1}{2}y)^2\cdot4ny\int sin(nxy)de^{-(x^2+y^2)}dy=$$

... I will update this post later

Comment: And now, *please add some personal input*. (Hmmm, weren't you already told that?)

Comment: Rewrite $\sin^2(nxy)$ as $\frac12\left(1 - \cos(2nxy)\right)$ and manipulate the second piece to a form you can apply [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma).

Answer (score 1):

Actually if you put your integral into Maple or Mathematica, which I did, it can perform the integration in closed form. Let denote your integral by $I$, then
$$
I=\frac{n}{8}\frac{n\sqrt{1+n^2}+\Re\text{arctanh}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+n^2}}{n}\right)}{(1+n^2)^{3/2}},
$$
where $\Re$ is for the real part. Now you can take the $n\to\infty$ limit to get 1/8 as the final answer to your question.

Another equally good method is if you expand the sine term as
$$
\sin^2(nxy)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}2^{2k-1}}{(2k)!}n^{2k}x^{2k}y^{2k}.
$$
Now one can integrate term by term. The $x$ and $y$ integrals can be done, yielding the same answer: $k!/2$. Finally we can re-sum the series in closed form, using Maple or Mathematica, and get the same 1/8 answer in the $n\to\infty$ limit.